# Wrong number of CUDA cores shown (GTX1070)

Tags: cudalink, installation, gpu, driver

I installed the CUDA toolkit by directly obeying to the [WRI instructions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/CUDALink/tutorial/Setup.html#10897850) and use MMA 11.1.1.0 as well as the paclet version 10.5.0. While CUDA's `deviceQuery` sample shows an abbreviated output of

```
Device 0: "GeForce GTX 1070"
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          8.0 / 8.0
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    6.1
Total amount of global memory:                 8192 MBytes (8589737984 bytes)
(15) Multiprocessors, (128) CUDA Cores/MP:     1920 CUDA Cores
```

the MMA `SystemInformation[]` only show 480 CUDA cores as can be seen here:

[image]

Does MMA count different from what Nvidia itself does or did I do something wrong while installing the package. Using both the latest CUDA drivers for macOS and the latest paclet for MMA I am quite sure the problem is not related to deprecated drivers.

Comment: This is an old post, but I just installed an RTX 3090 and my CUDA Core Count is "Indeterminate", so Mathematica can't use all of the cores since it doesn't know how many I have. I have a feeling this is the case because there are more than 10,000 because if I set batch size to anything over 10k, it sets it back down to 10k in NetTrain.