# Target system specification is not available for NVIDIA CUDA Compiler installation

Tags: cudalink, gpu, ccompilerdriver

I Installed Mathematica correctly and it indeed found my GPU. 
My case is exactly the same as :

[the same issue link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/160670/nvcc-cuda-compiler-not-showing-up)

However, it is not answered.

Does anyone know the reason?

My case:

```
CUDAQ[]
True

CUDAInformation[]
{1->{Name->GeForce 940M,Clock Rate->1176000,Compute Capabilities->5.,GPU Overlap->1,Maximum Block Dimensions->{1024,1024,64},Maximum Grid Dimensions->{2147483647,65535,65535},Maximum Threads Per Block->1024,Maximum Shared Memory Per Block->49152,Total Constant Memory->65536,Warp Size->32,Maximum Pitch->2147483647,Maximum Registers Per Block->65536,Texture Alignment->512,Multiprocessor Count->3,Core Count->96,Execution Timeout->1,Integrated->False,Can Map Host Memory->True,Compute Mode->Default,Texture1D Width->65536,Texture2D Width->65536,Texture2D Height->65536,Texture3D Width->4096,Texture3D Height->4096,Texture3D Depth->4096,Texture2D Array Width->16384,Texture2D Array Height->16384,Texture2D Array Slices->2048,Surface Alignment->512,Concurrent Kernels->True,ECC Enabled->False,TCC Enabled->False,Total Memory->2147483648}}

CUDADriverVersion[]
388.73
```

HOWEVER::::

```
CUDACCompilers[]

{}
```

If I run

```
secondKernel = 
 CUDAFunctionLoad[secondKernelCode, 
  "secondKernel", {{"Float"}, "Float", _Integer}, 16]

"Target system specification \"TargetSystemID\" -> \
\("Windows-x86-64\"\) is not available for \
\(TraditionalForm\`\"NVIDIA CUDA Compiler\"\) installation \
\("C:\\Users\\z3026\\AppData\\Roaming\\
Mathematica\\Paclets\\Repository\\CUDAResources-Win64-10.5.0\\
CUDAToolkit\\bin")"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an issue of incompatibility of VC and CUDA. For the laptop hardware, VC2013 should be appropriate for CUDA 7.